# `redirect_uri is missing or too long` on External login

Tags: asp.net, .net-core, identityserver4

Only when using External login I get:

```
fail: IdentityServer4.Validation.AuthorizeRequestValidator[0]
      redirect_uri is missing or too long
```

My `redirect_uri` in the client config is "http://localhost:1234/signin-callback" but I don't get this error when logging in with password.

```
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult ExternalLogin(string provider, string returnUrl = null)
    {
        var redirectUrl = Url.Action("ExternalLoginCallback", "Controller", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl });
        var properties = _signInManager.ConfigureExternalAuthenticationProperties(provider, redirectUrl);
        return Challenge(properties, provider);
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl = null, string remoteError = null)
    {
        if (remoteError != null)
        {
            return BadRequest(remoteError);
        }
        var info = await _signInManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
        if (info == null)
        {
            return BadRequest("no login info");
        }
        var result = await _signInManager.ExternalLoginSignInAsync(info.LoginProvider, info.ProviderKey, isPersistent: false);
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            return Redirect(returnUrl); // debug gets to here where we redirect to "/connect/authorize/login?client_id=my-client"
        }
        return BadRequest();
    }
```

This code successfully signs in but when it redirects to "/connect/authorize/login?client_id=my-client" it returns the error. What should I look for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am too quick to post a question.

It needs to redirect to `/connect/authorize/login?client_id=my-client&redirect_uri=http://localhost:1234/signin-callback` not just `/connect/authorize/login?client_id=my-client`.

I was passing `ExternalLogin()` `/ExternalLogin?provider=[provider]&returnUrl=[plain text url with escaping '&']` when it needs `/ExternalLogin?provider=[provider]&returnUrl=[encoded url]`.